# How i use 'withChangesForTables' in my project, of the best way?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, watermelondb

i'm used Watermelon DB in my project react native >= 0.60, and i have a question, how i use 'withChangesForTables' in my project, of the best way ?

i'm try this:

```
import { useDatabase } from '@nozbe/watermelondb/hooks'

export default function Lists() {
  const database = useDatabase()

  database.withChangesForTables(['lists'], () => {
  /// anything
  })
}
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?